# Error con Angular Date Pipe en producción en servidor Firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, date, pipe

Tengo el siguiente problema, en modo developer, me funciona todo correctamente, cuando hago el deploy en firebase, ya no se ven más las fechas con date pipe y me arroja el siguiente error: "ERROR Error: NG02100", me canse de googlear y no saco nada en concreto, según investigue esta todo bien configurado.

AppModule.ts:

```
providers: [interceptorProvider, { provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'es-AR' } ],
```

ejemplo de pipe date en el codigo HTML5:

```
<p class="fecha">{{trabajo.fechaInicio | date:'MMMM  yyyy'}} </p>
```

No tengo idea de por que en producción no anda y en desarrollo si. Agradecería mucho su ayuda!!

Answer (score 0):

En mi caso el problema se generaba porque desde el back mandaba la fecha formateada con `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ`, esta fecha al llegar al front no se transformaba en un date de angular, por lo que no puede aplicar el pipe en el html. Cambié el formato de la fecha en el back por `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` (por cierto mi back está hecho en java) y funcionó.

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/344422)